# Why is my shortcut to replace text inserting the replacement twice?

Tags: shortcuts-app

(OSX 13.1) I made a shortcut in Shortcuts called "Text->HTML->Make Italic". Its actions are:

- Receive Text from Quick Input
- Replace `(.*)` with `<i>$1</i>` in Shortcut Input (use Regular Expressions)
- Stop and output Updated Text

When I highlight `a word` and right click to run Services->Text->HTML->Make Italic, the text is transformed to:

`<i>a word</i><i></i>`

Do I need to do something differently or is this a bug? Thanks!

These are the shortcut settings: [image: shortcut screenshot]

Comment: We need to see the actual shortcut to diagnose. Can you please  [edit] your question  with screen shot(s) of your shortcut?

Comment: @Allan I added the screenshot, thanks. Is there any other info I should add?

Comment: Perhaps .* is too broad? Might the input include a null character, or line break, which is being treated as a second argument? Also, I know that in Automator, there's a risk of inputs 'multiplying' the output as the chain of actions grows.

Comment: I have limited AppleScript experience (I prefer Bash). Just out of curiosity…why do you have “Regular Expression” checked? [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) is a very specific language.

Comment: @Allan `()` is a match group and `.*` is a wildcard regular expression. Together they capture (all) text and store it as a match.

Answer (score 1):

By experimenting, I found there is a bug in Shortcuts that means the substitution that changes the end (`^`) has to come first. After that I can add the starting tag to the beginning. This version works:

[image: new substitution settings]